# PHP Calculate a large integer calculations

Tags: php, integer, rsa

I am creating a PHP script for my website that will be requested by a client. The server has to respond with the appropriate message and also a signature using RSA. In order for the signature to be generated it must preform two (or one combined) pow and mod. The equation is `s = m^d (mod n)`. And In most cases `s`,`m`, and `d` are extremely large integer numbers such as

```
4469734404104096837429764580934845061283523736702527402872742051805240505404664615264967782650887385837644037614299958863676630939441707937567787879563772416127260032333805678693381552565842160204683672959392802705913819156703613379573565738349149235585010164952052778408063647208096771173475093154490917974997899948301207462141742218985531732928507187811450511092706499289326888705457236944966320563788206136403616537412670548400617858178511373887544380273500238451544917864640793244156569047773433074906247791466420876530066966827069605060742050929459254119941389687342853034996153871651890210106384724986072757985
```

I've tried many PHP libraries such as BCMath, phpseclib and GMP, and none have been able to handle the size of the numbers by either not giving an answer, erroring out or responding with an absurdly wrong answer.

Does anyone know a library that can preform large pow/mod (powmod) operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was https://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger and that when I tried to use the library the first time I was A: using the wrong function and B: I was looking at the wrong datapoint to compare it with when I used the right function.

Answer (score 0):

phpseclib is a

> pure-PHP implementations of an arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic
>   library, fully PKCS#1 (v2.1) compliant RSA, DES, 3DES, RC4, Rijndael,
>   AES, Blowfish, Twofish, SSH-1, SSH-2, SFTP, and X.509

It has it's own implementation of `BigInteger` to store such large files. Using this library also makes implementing your own RSA liv obsolete.

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php

Comment: Would I have to create a new key pair with this or could I use my existing numbers?

Comment: Because I'd like to just keep it simple and just use the BigInteger library to do the calculations by themselves to make it more simple